# Facebook JS SDK FB.logout() doesn't terminate user session

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm attempting to log a user out of facebook with the Facebook JS SDK, however calling:

```
FB.logout(function(response){
    console.log(response);
});
```

returns:
response.status == "connected"

And only after refreshing the page does the SDK realize that the session has ended. Anyone know what could be causing this behavior? This code previously worked in my application and has recently started behaving this way.

Another example using FireBug:

[image]

Comment: When calling the logout and before refreshing your page, if you go on Facebook are you still connected ?
If you call the logout twice in a row, is it the same response ? (if not isn't it just a matter of timing between calls & response ?)
(And, even if it's not answering the "why" part, can't you fix this by reloading the page in the response ?)
Oh and, last one, "undefined" is another console.log i presume ?

Comment: @Flow' S, Yes 'undefined' is an irrelevant console log. FB.logout() does log the user out of facebook, but the current page FB object doesn't realize it until after a refresh. I would strongly prefer not to have to manually refresh the page after the user logs out. Also I attempted to delete the fbsr_ cookie to see if this removed it -- no effect. This previously worked and only recently changed. Also, I tried the same test on hulu.com which uses the FB JS SDK, same results. Is this possibly a bug in the SDK?

Comment: I'm currently use `FB.getLoginStatus` from `FB.logout` callback to ensure JS-SDK forget about user.

Comment: TOP TIP: There are a tonne of nuances with FB API, on many levels. Do yourself a favor and use `https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/debug.js` instead of `https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js` during primary development. You'll see lovely blue debug messages in the console, which you can filter by filename (debug.js) :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/245362365535898?browse=search_4f112135664703a96454690
This is a bug in the JS SDK that has now been fixed and it should get pushed in not too long.
Until then you can do the following

```
FB.logout(function(response) {
  FB.Auth.setAuthResponse(null, 'unknown');
  ...
});
```

Comment: Thank you worked with me and solve my big problem, appreciate :)

Comment: I tried it, but, the function(response) never executed, any idea ?

Comment: @JaredEitnier What doesn't work? And what is version 3? As the main contributor to the JS SDK, it's funny that I haven't heard of this :)

Comment: I somehow in my tired mind yesterday mixed up the PHP SDK & JS SDK I think haha. Anyway, dumb comment gone :)

Comment: it seems logout success, but for me the statements after `FB.Auth.setAuthResponse(null, 'unknown');` is not calling, like a simple alert()

Comment: Anyway, I solved the problem by using `setTimeout` for my function call before the line `FB.Auth.setAuthResponse`, sounds a little bit tricky.

Comment: `Auth` object doesn't exist in my `FB` object. Maybe because of Facebook Javascript SDK version.
What would be the solution for FB 2.5 ?

Comment: @manonthemoon, then it's not the JS SDK you have loaded. Auth is part of the core configuration.

Answer (score 3):

See http://hustoknow.blogspot.com/2012/01/dealing-with-zombie-facebook-cookies.html

When you logout, a cross-domain request gets sent to Facebook to invalidate the session.  When you hit reload, another request gets sent to Facebook's site -- since FB recognizes the cookie as invalid, it correctly deletes the cookie from your browser.

I suspect it's a regexp bug in how they forgot to parse the fbm_ cookie, recently introduced in the last day or so. I'm just surprised that this fix hasn't been pushed.

Answer (score 3):

```
FB.logout(function(response) {
  ...
});
```

This FB.logout method is working 100%.
The problem is that users are trying to call it from localhost which is not working.

Please try call it from server.

Comment: On my case , yes , you are right. It does not work on localhost. However I not sure your word (working 100%).

Comment: This is working for me in localhost with XAMPP. Might be that the devs are not using https

Comment: Wow yes this does seem to be correct even today, and even with https. It literally doesn't seem to do anything on localhost

Answer (score 3):

As i have spent lots of time to find out exactly what is happening in the FB logout, felt better to share it here for others.

First thing, Please read the documentation [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.logout/)

> A person logs into Facebook, then logs into your app. Upon logging out from your app, the person is still logged into Facebook.

this point killed 90% my of time. When i have logged in from facebook.com and trying to test login button in my application, it worked as expected, but logout was not terminating the session.

Solution or Fix: As per the scenarios given in the document, it will not terminate the user session, as the login is **not initiated** from the app, it is from facebook.com. so in this case, fb will not terminate the session.

When you login into fb, from your app (fresh login as username and password), system consider the source/trigger of the session as your app. so when you do logout (window.FB.logout or FB.logout) it will terminate user session completely.

**So please logout from facebook.com before testing login functionality in your app.**

As other mentioned, use below code to logout

```
FB.logout(function(response) {
 // response from logout will have authResponse with access_token so better to test the status as it will return "unknown"
 if(response.status !== "connected") { } \\ do some check on the status of the login before considering successful logout.
});
```

Last but not least: to test from localhost, please update the settings in FB APP

1. Update **App Domains** to **localhost**
2. **Site URL** under **Websites** to **http://localhost:3000/**

This will solve issues faced in testing from localhost

Comment: Looks like this is what happening.  But this behavior is strange, different from Google where logging out will only invalidate the oauth grant on your website, not actually log the user out of his Google account.  Edit: ok I think Facebook intentionally does this to enforce a single FB login across all websites.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same experience with the `FB.Logout()` not working as advertised.  As a workaround I use the below javascript function to check if the user is logged in and if so, redirect to https://www.facebook.com/logout.php with the URL of the subsequent page to load and their access token:

```
    function reallylogout() {
      FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
           window.location = "https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?next=" +
             'URL to redirect to' +
             "&access_token=" + response.authResponse.accessToken;
        } else {
           $("#loginButtonDiv").show();
           $("#logoutButtonDiv").hide();
        }
      });
    }
```

The show/hide bit is just jQuery to show or hide divs that have a login and logout button in them.  The logout button's onclick triggers the reallyLogout() function.

This works for my app.

Comment: This works, but I'm really looking for a solution that can trigger the FB JS SDK to 'forget' about the logged in user without performing a page refresh. Up until a few weeks ago this worked, and I have not made any changes since then.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced similar kind of problem. I've used `FB.getLoginStatus()` after Logout.

Answer (score 0):

It appears broken in Facebook.  On FB rell you can login but the logout function does nothing.    http://www.fbrell.com/auth/all-in-one

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys I found a solution for this:

Put up onClick event for the logout `<a>` tag like this

```
onclick="FB.logout(function() { document.location.reload(); });"
```

All together:

```
<a href="#" 
   id="auth-logoutlink"
   style="float:left;font-size: small;"
   onclick="FB.logout(function() { document.location.reload(); });">
   [logout]
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

in asp.net mvc application i did it as following.

---

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="logOff">Log out</a>
```

---

```
$(function () {


    $(".logOff").click(function () {

        //check if logout is 
        FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
            console.log('inside login status');
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                // the user is logged in and has authenticated your
                // app, and response.authResponse supplies
                // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed
                // request, and the time the access token 
                // and signed request each expire
                var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
                var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                FB.logout(function (response) {

                    FB.Auth.setAuthResponse(null, 'unknown');

                });
            } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
                // but has not authenticated your app

            } else {
                // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
                console.log('response status not logged in');
            }
        });
        window.location.href = '@Url.Action("LogOff", "Account")';

    });
```

Comment: `FB.Auth`, Auth doesn't exist for me using Facebook SDK 2.5.

Answer (score -1):

It may be doesn't work because you don't include your Facebook app key. It works for me like this:

```
 Ext.get('auth-logoutlink').on('click', function(){   
                  FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
                    if (response.authResponse) {
                       window.location = "https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?confirm=1&api_key=**MYAPIKEY**&next=" +
                         '**MYWEBSITEURL**' +
                         "&access_token=" + response.authResponse.accessToken;
                    } else {
                       //HIDE **LOGOUT BUTTON**
                       //SHOW **LOGIN BUTTON**
                    }
                  });
        });
```