# Facebook JS SDK logout on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, authentication, facebook-javascript-sdk

I was wondering how to do this on page load. It is working with "onClick", i.e `<a href="#" onClick="FB.logout()">Logout</a>` <- Works

but if I have something like this done:

```
 // INIT (file 1)
 $ ->
    $('body').prepend('<div id="fb-root"></div>')

    $.ajax
        url: "#{window.location.protocol}//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"
        dataType: 'script'
        cache: true

    window.fbAsyncInit = ->
        FB.init(appId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx', cookie: true)

       $('#facebook_sign_in').click (e) ->
          e.preventDefault()
          FB.login (response) ->
            window.location = '/auth/facebook/callback' if response.authResponse


    // FILE 2

    <script src="file1.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
        FB.logout(); <- Nothing happens
    });
```

Debugger says, that FB variable is not defined. But why on earth it would be undefined, if onClick works like a charm ?

So, is it somehow possible ?

Comment: IT seems when the time FB.logout() is being called the FB.init() has not been initialized by then.

Comment: Any fix for that to try ? :(

Answer (score 0):

It seems that when you use the FB api it has not been loaded yet.

Using `$.ajax()` to load the FB `all.js` script might be the cause, do either add a callback function to it, or load the script in the head of your html.

Comment: My script in fact, IS located in head. I've even tried to make FB global (window.FB = FB or window.FB.init), but now everything is "undefined"

Comment: I dont mean your script, I mean the script to load the FB stuff: http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
            FB.logout(function(response) {
               FB.Auth.setAuthResponse(null, 'unknown');
             });
        });
```

this refers to [Facebook JS SDK FB.logout() doesn't terminate user session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8817569/facebook-js-sdk-fb-logout-doesnt-terminate-user-session)